# Gazebo camera plugin not sending data to ros

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, camera, gazebo-9, ardupilot

I am on ubuntu 18.04 using gazebo 9 and ros melodic. I am able to run roslaunch and open gazebo with ros and connect it to ardupilot SITL. When i check rostopic in another terminal i am not getting any camera data. I run my own launch file which launches a world that includes a runway and an iris copter. I am able to see a gimbal and camera on the vehicle itself but when i run "rostopic list" i am not getting any camera data.[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.